# Cascading dropdownlist in MVC not Working

Tags: jquery, crm

Please assist I have an issue with populating my cascading dropdownlist.
Please see code below. I have a method to get Suburbs but its failing with the exception in the JavaScript.

```
public ActionResult LoadTown()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ALBERTON", Value = "1" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "BEDFORDVIEW", Value = "2" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "BENONI", Value = "3" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "BOKSBURG", Value = "4" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "BRAKPAN", Value = "5" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "EDENVALE", Value = "6" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "GERMISTON", Value = "7" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "KEMPTON PARK", Value = "8" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "NIGEL", Value = "9" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "SPRINGS", Value = "10" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "BRAKPAN", Value = "11" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "EDENVALE", Value = "12" });
        ViewData["town"] = li;
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetSurburbs(string id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> states = new List<SelectListItem>();
        switch (id)
        {
            case "ALBERTON":
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ALBERANTE", Value = "1" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "AALBERTON", Value = "2" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ALBERTSDAL", Value = "3" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ALRODE", Value = "4" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ALRODE SOUTH", Value = "5" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ARTON", Value = "6" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "BASSONIA ROCK", Value = "7" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "BRACKENDOWNS", Value = "8" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "BRACKENHURST", Value = "9" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "EDEN PARK", Value = "10" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "EDEN PARK WEST", Value = "11" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ELANDSFONTEIN 108-IR", Value = "12" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "FLORENTIA", Value = "13" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "GENERAAL ALBERTSPARK", Value = "14" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "GREENFIELDS", Value = "15" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "KLIPRIVIERSBERG 106-IR", Value = "16" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "KERALA", Value = "17" });
```

Here is my code in the VIEW

```
<div class="form-group">
                                                        @Html.Label("Select Town", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                                                        <div class="col-md-12">


                                                                @Html.DropDownList("Town", new SelectList(new string[] { "ALBERTON", "BEDFORDVIEW", "BENONI", "BOKSBURG", "BRAKPAN", "EDENVALE" , "GERMISTON", "KEMPTON PARK", "NIGEL", "SPRINGS", "BRAKPAN", "EDENVALE" }), new { @class = "dropdown1"})

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        @Html.Label("Select Surburb", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                                                        <div class="col-md-12">

                                                            @Html.DropDownList("Select Surburb", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a Surburb")


                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
```

Pleae see Javascript code here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
    $("#Town").change(function () {
        $("#Surburb").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSurburbs")', // we are calling json method

            dataType: 'json',

            data: { id: $("#Town").val() },
           // here we are get value of selected country and passing same value


            success: function (states) {
                // states contains the JSON formatted list
                // of states passed from the controller

                $.each(states, function (i, state) {
                    $("#Surburb").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' +
                     state.Text + '</option>');
                // here we are adding option for States

                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve Surburbs.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is the error message shown?

Comment: Failed to retrieve Surburbs, the error in my JQuery code.

Comment: Change the ajax type to 'GET'

Comment: If you change it to GET, you'll need to change the last line of `public JsonResult GetSurburbs(string id)` to allow GETs - you've not included the last line, so it *could* be that you're not returning the JSON correctly from the Action - please add the last line of `GetSurburbs` (ps it's Suburbs)

Comment: Here is the last line
    return Json(new SelectList(states, "Value", "Text"));
}